# VBA excel passing an array to sub fired by button

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

As in title I would like to pass an array to the sub which is executed by a button (That's why I don't know ho to pass it to the sub). Array is calculated in the Sheet before you can exectue sub with the button.
I've tried using:

```
Option Explicit On
Public My_array(1 to 10)
```

But I have received an error that I can not do that command with array, const etc.

What is the correct way to do it?

Comment: What do you mean "Array is calculated in the Sheet before you can execute sub with the button"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there is some terminology we can try to clear up: you're not actually *passing* the variable to the button's procedure.  A publicly scoped variable is going to be available within that procedure and does not need to be "passed".

**Note:** I'm not sure what you mean by "Array is calculated in the Sheet".  Unless you are using some event procedure to calculate an array in memory (probably you are not, because you don't have the array scoped or declared properly to do this...), this statement can't possibly be true.

Your declaration should be like:

```
Public myArray(1 To 10) As Variant 'or As String, As Double, etc.
```

You can omit the `As ...` part and it will be type Variant. if you need more strongly-typed array, then you will need to specify.

Also, `On` is not a legal keyword after the `Option Explict` statement. So, remove that. But keep `Option Explicit` in all of your modules.

The error message you receive hints at the solution: You can't put public declarations in object modules. An object module is a Worksheet, Workbook, UserForm, or Class module in the VBE.

You can only put these declarations in a normal code module.

**Solution:** Move the declaration of `myArray` to a normal code module.

Comment: The `As Variant` part isn't necessary. VB6/VBA will make any variable without a type into a variant.